# Spring Security/OAuth: mapping between Principal's authority and role in @RolesAllowed

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm playing around with Spring OAuth, implemented an authorization server and a  resource server. The resource server uses user-info-uri to decode a token.

Methods (some) in the resource server's controllers are protected by @RolesAllowed (also tried @PreAuthorize, same effect).

```
@RolesAllowed("ROLE_USER")
//@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/test-user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testUser() {
    return "You are User!";
}
```

There are three users, managed on the authorization server side: user1 with ROLE_ADMIN, user2 and user3 with ROLE_USER.

The resource service accepts the token, generated by the authorization server (password grant flow) and asks the user-info-uri about the principal details. So far works as designed.

But what then happens, is what I do not understand. The principal structure (say, for user2, having ROLE_USER), contains a correct authority (for the example purpose I made a manual call to the user-info-uri):

```
  "principal": {
    "password": null,
    "username": "user2",
    "authorities": [
      {
        "authority": "ROLE_USER"
      }
    ],
    "accountNonExpired": true,
    "accountNonLocked": true,
    "credentialsNonExpired": true,
    "enabled": true
  },
```

And it seems to be correctly deserialized at the resource server side:

```
2016-08-31 12:30:37.530 DEBUG 32992 --- [nio-9998-exec-1] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String org.cftap.OAuthResourceController.testUser(); target is of class [org.cftap.OAuthResourceController]; Attributes: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_USER]
2016-08-31 12:30:37.530 DEBUG 32992 --- [nio-9998-exec-1] o.s.s.a.i.a.MethodSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication@ed03ae2: Principal: user2; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, tokenType=BearertokenValue=<TOKEN>; Granted Authorities: {authority=ROLE_USER}
2016-08-31 12:30:37.530 DEBUG 32992 --- [nio-9998-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@4cf62e16, returned: 0
2016-08-31 12:30:37.530 DEBUG 32992 --- [nio-9998-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250Voter@11e4338f, returned: -1
2016-08-31 12:30:37.530 DEBUG 32992 --- [nio-9998-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@3d5cb07f, returned: -1
2016-08-31 12:30:37.531 DEBUG 32992 --- [nio-9998-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@2724a21f, returned: 0
2016-08-31 12:30:37.536 DEBUG 32992 --- [nio-9998-exec-1] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Wed Aug 31 12:30:37 CEST 2016, principal=user2, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
2016-08-31 12:30:37.546 DEBUG 32992 --- [nio-9998-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
```

But, as you see in the debug log, the RoleVoter (and JSR250 one) votes against it (although the allowed role and the authority of the principal fit together), hence sending 403 back.

Did I miss something important?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with
`@RolesAllowed("USER")` instead of `@RolesAllowed("ROLE_USER")`.

Eventually you could use `hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")` or  `hasRole("USER")` instead of `hasRole("ROLE_USER")` .

These are changes from Spring 4, you are probably using some old Spring 3 documentation / articles.

Comment: @RolesAllowed("USER") helped